# Laravel edit view returns all checkboxes checked

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel, crud, checked

I have two tables, basic stuff, categories, and articles. 
Categories:

- id
- name

Articles:

- id
- title
- category_id ...

Relationships

Category model:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Article');
}
```

Articles model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}
```

edit and upadte methods in controller:

```
public function getEdit($id)
    {
        $categories = Category::get();
        $articles = Article::with('category')->find($id);
        return View::make('articles.edit', compact('articles', 'categories'), array('title' => 'Promena clanka'));
    }

    public function updateEdit($id)
    {

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), Article::$rules);

        if($validation->passes()) {
            $article = Article::find($id);
            $article->title = Input::get('title');
            $article->slug = Slug::make(Input::get('title'));
            $article->body = Input::get('body');
            $article->category_id = Input::get('category_id');
            $article->tag = Input::get('tag');
            $article->visibility = Input::get('visibility');
            $article->update();
            return Redirect::route('dashboard')->with('message', 'Uspesno promenjen clanak');
        }

        return Redirect::route('dashboard/article/edit/' . $id )->withErrors($validation);
    }
```

How can I dispay only checked checkbox that has category_id value. So far i get all checked.

```
@if(count($categories))
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <div class="checkbox">
            {{Form::checkbox('category_id', $category->id ) }} <span>{{Str::Title($category->name) }}</span>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

How should I solve this?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The `Form::checkbox` takes an optional third parameter to set the checkbox to checked. You could use `isset` on `$category->id` which will return a boolean (true if `$category->id` is set and not null).

So within your loop you could do something like this:

```
{{Form::checkbox('category_id', $category->id, isset($category->id)}}
```